# Concurrency of A'L, B'M, C'N.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Need some help with the following problem.

**Problem:** In $\triangle ABC$ the midpoints of $BC$, $AC$, $AB$ are $L, M,$ and $N$ respectively, and the points on the circumcircle opposite to $A, B,$ and $C$ are $A', B',$ and $C'$ respectively. Prove that the lines $A'L$, $B'M$, $C'N$ are concurrent at the orthocenter.

[image: Illustration]

Kind of at a loss on how to start, though I've tried using power of a point and contradiction without much effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$AXCB'$ is a parallelogram with center $M$.  This easy to prove fact (use $AB' \perp AB$) and its equivalents for the other two sides show that:

the dilation of the plane by a factor of $2$, centered at $X$, carries $L,M$ and $N$ to $A', B',$ and $C'$.

Really that dilation carries the nine-point circle of $ABC$ to the circumcircle.  Six points on the circumcircle are drawn in the diagram, and the other three are the reflections of $X$ in the sides of the triangle.

Comment: Let's mention [Thales' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem) as key to this orthogonality you mention, and let's also explicitely mention $CB'\bot CB$ by the same argument. With this it's really easy. Nice!

Comment: @MvG, it's probably easiest to "see" it all at once from the configuration for the nine-point circle.  Double it from the orthocenter and all is done.  I added an edit.

Answer (score 4):

The triangle $LMN$ is the image of $ABC$ by the homothety $h_1$ centered on the gravity center of the triangle $ABC$ (which you should add to the picture ; let's call it $G$) and scaling $-1/2$.

The triangle $A'B'C'$ is the image of $ABC$ by the homothety $h_2$ centered on $Y$ (the center of the circumscribed circle of $ABC$) and scaling $-1$.

Hence $LMN$ is the image of $A'B'C'$ by $h_1 \circ h_2^{-1}$, a composition of two homotheties of scaling $-1$ and $-1/2$, which has to be an homothety of scaling $-1 \times -1/2 = 1/2$. In particular, the lines $(A'L), (B'M)$ and $(C'N)$ all pass through the center $X$ of this homothety.

But what is the center of this homothety ? $X$ is fixed by $h_1 \circ h_2^{-1}$, so put $X' = h_2^{-1}(X)$, so that $X = h_1(X')$. Then we must have $\vec{YX'} = - \vec{YX}$ and $\vec{GX} = - \frac 1 2 \vec{GX'}$.
Hence $\vec{GX} = - \frac 1 2 (\vec {GY} - \vec {YX})$, and so $\frac 3 2 \vec{GX} = \vec{YX}$ : $X$ is the barycenter of $(G,3)(Y,-2)$

Then it is a well-known fact about triangles that this point is the orthocenter of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm reopening this old thread, but I can't help my self since it is so beautiful.

Set vector origin at a circum-center $Y$. Then we have $H=A+B+C$ (Hamilton's theorem) and $A' = -A$.

Then reflection of $A'$ across $L$ is $A'' = 2L-A' = A+B+C=H$ since $L = {1\over 2}(B+C)$. So $A'L$ goes through $H$ and so does $B'M$ and $C'N$. Q.E.D.